# Is there an Amazon.com API to retrieve product reviews for a user?

Tags: amazon-web-services

```
http://www.amazon.com/gp/profile/profile_id
```

This will show the reviews written by a user. 
Is there an api that can retrieve the user reviews, given a profile id? 
My goal is to get number of reviews a user has submitted, review dates and stars.